# Unable to import modules in nestjs

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-config

I have three modules `moviesModule`, `searchModule` and `configModule` that I am trying to import

```
import { CategoryService } from './../category/category.service';

import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { DatabaseModule } from './../database/database.module';

import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

import { MoviesModule } from '../movies/movies.module';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
import { SearchModule } from '../search/search.module';

import { PostController } from '../post/post.controller';
import { PostService } from '../post/post.service';
import { CategoryController } from '../category/category.controller';

@Module({
  imports: [
    DatabaseModule, MoviesModule //Error after adding here
  ],
  controllers: [AppController, PostController, CategoryController],
  providers: [AppService, PostService, CategoryService],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

As soon as I add any of the above three modules, I am getting error:

```
Command failed: taskkill /pid 27448 /T /F
ERROR: The process "27448" not found.

Debugger listening on ws://localhost:9229/7e3b0f6b-4b30-48d8-95cf-8dd5e9865436
Debugger listening on ws://localhost:9229/7e3b0f6b-4b30-48d8-95cf-8dd5e9865436
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
D:\projects\my-apps\interview-prep\dist\apps\backend\main.js:65501
    cookieAttributeList.unparsed ??= []
                                 ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??='
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1001:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
    at Function.Module._load (D:\projects\my-apps\interview-prep\node_modules\.pnpm\@nrwl+js@15.8.6_dy3bcy5rzsznsjo6teutqltnt4\packages\js\src\executors\node\node-with-require-overrides.ts:16:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:101:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\projects\my-apps\interview-prep\node_modules\.pnpm\@nrwl+js@15.8.6_dy3bcy5rzsznsjo6teutqltnt4\packages\js\src\executors\node\node-with-require-overrides.ts:20:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would hazard a guess that your node version is on 14 or lower. The [nullish coalescing assignment (`??=`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_assignment) was introduced to Node in version 15 (stable major version 16) and should be available from there on